# How can I call a function from a separate file when using Discord bot with interactions.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

### Here is my main.py script:

```
import interactions
from Commands.music import join_voice_channel


# Tokens
bot = interactions.Client(token= "my_bot_token")  



# Login confirmation of bot in terminal
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Alleskönner is ready!")
    print(f"Interaction.py version = ",interactions.__version__)



# The first command
@bot.command(
    name="my_first_command",
    description="This is the first command I made"
)
async def my_first_command(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    await ctx.send("Hi there!")


# Booting up the bot
bot.start()
```

### Music.py script

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials

# Set up Spotify authentication
client_credentials_manager = SpotifyClientCredentials(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
                                                      client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=client_credentials_manager)

async def join_voice_channel(ctx):
    # Check if the command invoker is in a voice channel
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        voice_client = ctx.voice_client

        # Check if the bot is already in a voice channel
        if voice_client is None:
            await channel.connect()
        else:
            await voice_client.move_to(channel)
    else:
        await ctx.send('You need to be in a voice channel to use this command.')
```

How do I call the function `join_voice_channel()` in `main.py` so that when the `main.py` script is executed and the `join VC` slash command is used it runs the function that is saved in `music.py`?

### Additional Context

- I am using the interactions library `4.4.0`.
- The `join_voice_channel` function is intended to be triggered by a slash command.
- I want to execute the function stored in `music.py` when the `join VC` slash command is used.

Comment: Please look at Command Cogs, it's what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

### How to use multiple files

As [Clement Genninasca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15810170/clement-genninasca) said, you'll need cogs for this.
`add_cog` in `discord.ext.commands.Bot()` can do this.

### Implementation

For this example, I'll use two files. `main.py` and `file2.py`.

In `main.py`:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import file2

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)  # commands.Bot() can add cogs

@client.event
async def on_connect():
    await client.add_cog(file2.voice(client))  # add cog from file2
```

*Notes: `discord.Client()` can't use cogs. See the docs [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client).*

In `file2.py`:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


class voice(commands.Cog):  #create commands.Cog class to put commands in
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()  # test cog command
    async def test_cog(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello!")
```

### Output

[image: Output]

### Slash commands example

In `main.py`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.load_extension('file2')
    await client.tree.sync()
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
```

In `file2.py`:

```py
class voice(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="test_cog", description="Testing")
    async def test_cog(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("Hello!")


async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
  await bot.add_cog(voice(bot))
```

Output:

[image: output]

### Helpful resources

- [Cog docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/cogs.html)
- [On connect docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=on_connect#discord.on_connect)
- [discord.ext.commands.bot docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=discord%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot)
- [Syncing slash commands video that I used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HjyP4_h9Ajg)
- [A bunch of slash command cog examples](https://gist.github.com/AbstractUmbra/a9c188797ae194e592efe05fa129c57f)